# Pass values of yaml file as environment variables from dockerfile

Tags: linux, bash, docker, yaml, dockerfile

I have a yaml file:

I want the values of topics which is test-topic and url which is localhost:9092 to be an environment variables.

build.yaml

```
  triggers:
    myTrigger:
      kind: cron-job
      attributes:
        initialOffset: latest
        topics:
          - TOPIC
        url:
          - URL
```

I am using this file inside the dockerfile.

Dockerfile

```
ENV TOPIC="test-topic" \
    URL="localhost:80"


ADD build.yaml .
```

While running the docker file is there any way i can pass the values of topics and url as environment variables?

**docker run image -e ??**

Comment: As you've shown it, no.  You might be able to use a code-level tool to have environment variable values supercede these config-file values, or use a tool like `envsubst` to replace file contents at container startup time, but on its own, Docker won't rewrite files for you.

Comment: If you specify environment variables when starting container, they will be available to executing processes inside docker image. If program, which uses build.yaml, can take care of these environment variables then you can do your way.